# Don't rewrite link generator with dinamic route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, prefix

In my code I created a route with a prefix, this prefix is a slug of courses.

```php
Route::prefix('{course_slug}')->middleware('courses')->group(function () { ...
```

The URL is like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1/class/php/exams
```

It's all right, but now I need to rewrite my views, with a parameter of course.

```php
route('class.exams.index', ['course' => 'php'])
```

My question is, it's possible don't rewrite my views? There are the possibility to inject the parameter of course on generate link and don't change the code on the view?

Then keep the code so.

```php
route('class.exams.index')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. The solution is described on this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/default-route-parameters?page=1#reply=426656

The solution, on my case, was in the Middleware set a default param

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class SetRouteDomain
{
    private $url;

    public function __construct(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $course_default = Course::getDefault();

        $this->url->defaults([
            'course_slug' => isset($request->course_slug) ? $request->course_slug : $course_default->slug,
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then I don't needed to change the views.